# ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.create undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to create a database on the fly for a multitenant app, like so:

```
 def signup
        ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection "#{Rails.env}".to_sym
        @site = Site.new(title: params[:site_title], host: params[:site_host], template: 'bare')
        if(@site.save) 
            conn_config = ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config
            conn_config[:database] = @site.id
            conn_config[:host] = 'localhost'

            puts conn_config
            #ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection conn_config
            ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.database_configuration = conn_config
            ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.create
            %x[rake db:sites]
            @user = User.new(name: params[:name], email: params[:email], password: params[:password], password_confirmation: params[:password_confirm])
            if @user.save
            else
            end
        else

        end

    end
```

The Site gets created in the proper database, but if I try to use the `DatabaseTasks.create`, to create my site database, I get:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Couldn't create database for nil
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 445ms (ActiveRecord: 296.7ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):

app/controllers/auth_controller.rb:16:in `signup'
```

Line 16 is the create row. `puts conn_config` there gives me `{:adapter=>"postgresql", :encoding=>"unicode", :pool=>5, :database=>"869acf95-6945-4a50-8101-75ed7b813e12", :host=>"localhost"}`, so the id is definitely being set as the db name.

What's wrong here and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`> ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.create conn_config` or u make new taskclass and pass configuration

because

```
def create(*arguments)
configuration = arguments.first
$stderr.puts "Couldn't create database for #{configuration.inspect}"
```

Comment: That's a slight improvement. One line in the error changed & no DB still created: Couldn't create database for {:adapter=>"postgresql", :encoding=>"unicode", :host=>"localhost", :pool=>5, :database=>"00e2754a-a6fc-44d3-9a74-c24dcd5c406f"}

Comment: and where is configuration["host"]   configuration["port"] configuration["password"] and configuration["username"]

Comment: Specified those aswell. Couldn't create database for {:adapter=>"postgresql", :encoding=>"unicode", :host=>"localhost", :pool=>5, :database=>"cefbb4fa-d7e9-4045-a711-79912e325ce2", :password=>"[snipped]", :username=>"rando", :port=>5432} User does exist.

Comment: `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass
Couldn't create database for {:adapter=>"postgresql", :encoding=>"unicode", :host=>"localhost", :pool=>5, :database=>"cefbb4fa-d7e9-4045-a711-79912e325ce2", :password=>"-snip-", :username=>"rando", :port=>"5432"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 420ms (ActiveRecord: 266.8ms)



NoMethodError (undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/auth_controller.rb:15:in 'signup'  ` (deleted a empty line above, so 15 is now the create line)

Comment: try ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.create([conn_config])
but u will prolly get something like TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Comment: i think its better u try something create_current
example http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/ActiveRecord/Tasks/DatabaseTasks